# Standalone executable output is empty in C#

Tags: c#, python, web-crawler

Python-made standalone executable (pwc.exe) always outputs website html data to console of any website when i run it from command line.

But when i try to read that output to c# string, in most cases (it works good only on the very small websites) i get an empty string in c#.

1. Everything works fine in this situation

   - Command line: pwc.exe https://gopro.com/about-us gopro.com
   - C# arguments line: Arguments = "https://gopro.com/about-us gopro.com"
2. Console output is correct, but empty c# string

   - Command line: pwc.exe http://www.bbc.com www.bbc.com
   - C# arguments line: Arguments = "https://www.google.com www.google.com"

pwc.exe code:

`from lxml import html
import requests
import sys
url=sys.argv[1]
host=sys.argv[2]
headers = {'Host': host, 'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0', 'Accept' : 'Accept: text/css,*/*;q=0.1', 'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.5', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br', 'Connection':'keep-alive'}
r = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
r.encoding = 'UTF-8'
print (r.text)`

c# code:

```
        var proc = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"pwc.exe",
                Arguments = "https://www.bbc.com/about-us www.bbc.com",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
            }
        };

        proc.Start();
        string html = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

I need to get pwc.exe console output (utf8) to C# string. It looks like when i read output of the very small pages, everything works fine in C#.

p.s. Tried to read like this, but it didnt help:

```
while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
{
html = proc.ou.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because of these exceptions.

[image]

You can refer to below code to trace the errors in your output, May be you have to do some conversion from python side to receive correctly in C# Code.

```
private static void ProcessItem()
    {
        var process = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"dist\Webpy\webpy.exe",
                //Arguments = "https://gopro.com/about-us gopro.com",
                //Arguments = "https://www.google.com www.google.com",
                Arguments = "https://www.bbc.com/about-us www.bbc.com",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
            }
        };
        //* Set your output and error (asynchronous) handlers
        process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OutputHandler);
        process.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OutputHandler);
        //* Start process and handlers
        process.Start();
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();
        process.BeginErrorReadLine();
        process.WaitForExit();
    }

    static void OutputHandler(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
    {
        //* Do your stuff with the output (write to console/log/StringBuilder)
        Console.WriteLine(outLine.Data);
    }
```

Comment: This doesnt help. Finally, i wrote to file using python (import codecs to write utf8) and then read that file using c# and it went without any problems.

Comment: Thank you for letting us know the approach. I wrote above code for better debugging not as part of solutions.

Comment: I dont know why, but those OutputDataReceived events are not caught in both cases.